# Opera and extra space and scrolling

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, opera

[My website](http://toreyscheer.webs.com/) was designed for firefox, and now that I've got most of the stuff I'd like, I am trying to get standard functionality working on other browsers if nothing else.

One of the weirder errors I currently have (only in Opera 12.0), is that to the right of my page is a big empty space. Does anyone know what functionality in Opera might be causing this?

Note: If it helps I added borders, which actually duplicated the problem in Firefox (and possibly other browsers).

Comment: fix `position:relative; left:300px;`

Comment: @jasssonpet Oh, I see. I didn't give it a width, thanks :) Although I would have thought it would not have extended past the width of it's parent...

Comment: @jasssonpet Feel free to post as answer if you want.

Comment: @jasssonpet yup post it as an answer that would help to have the issue out of the open issues :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fix the div with `position:relative; left:300px;` style by giving it a width.